# Does the functor sending a DGA to its zeroth component admit a right adjoint?

Tags: adjoint-functors, differential-graded-algebras

Let $A$ be a ring and write $\underline{A}^\bullet$ for the associated trivial DGA. We have a functor
$$\mathrm{ev}_0\colon\mathbf{dgAlg}_{\underline{A}^\bullet}\longrightarrow\mathbf{Alg}_A$$
sending a DGA $(B^\bullet,\mathrm{d}^\bullet,\mu^{\bullet,\bullet})$ to the $A$-algebra $(B^0,\mu^{0,0})$. This functor has a left adjoint: the “de Rham complex relative to $A$ functor”
$$\Omega^\bullet_{(-)/A}\colon\mathbf{Alg}_A\longrightarrow\mathbf{dgAlg}_{\underline{A}^\bullet}$$
sending an $A$-algebra $B$ to $\Omega^\bullet_{B/A}$.

**Q:** Does $\mathrm{ev}_{0}$ also admit a right adjoint?